# How can I use a variable in the ASP.NET/Blazor _Layout.cshtml that I created in a different class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am **SO NEW** to ASP.NET/Blazor. I have been a Java guy for **MANY** years and have had to switch to this new technology, so please bear with me.

I have a "Constants" class `Constants.cs`:

```
namespace MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes{
    public class Constants{
        public const String myString01 = "the quick brown fox";
        public const String myString02 = "jumps over the lazy dog";
    }
}
```

Now in my `_Layout.cshtml` page I would like to use those constants, but I do not know how to do it.

```
<div>
    @{// Use my constant here}
</div>
```

I tried a **[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+variables+in+%22_Layout.cshtml%22)**, but didn't come up with much help.

---

**EDIT:** I have tried this:

```
<div>
    @{MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString01}
</div>
```

And received the error:

```
CS0426: The type name 'myString01' does not exist in the type 'Constants'.
```

Comment: `Constants.myString01` ?

Comment: Or, if you don't have the namespace imported: `MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString01`.

Comment: @gunr2171 I tried your suggestion, but get the error `CS0426: The type name 'myString01' does not exist in the type 'Constants'.

Comment: What code are you writing to cause the error? Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: @gunr2171 I edited my original post with what I tried. What I am working on is a fresh, out of the box Blazor page with nothing else changed except for what I am trying here.

Comment: Change `@{...}` to `@(...)`. `{ }` is for code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was going to say the same as gunr2171..

```
<div>
@(MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString01)
</div>
```

, will write the text.

Or you can write it as:

```
<div>
@MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString01
</div>
```

But if you want to do some string concationation, you need to use paranteses () for response write:

```
<div>
@(MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString01 + " " + MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString02)
</div>
```

Or with a code-block:

```
@{ 
string print = MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString01 + " " + MyAwesomeApplication.Web.Classes.Constants.myString02
}
<div>
@print
</div>
```